# How to make a pie chart smaller with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have my pie chart, and would like to make the circle smaller. 
On current size, I can not read one of the labels. (imported matplotlib as `plt`)

```
title('Distribuicao recomendada de calorias por refeicao', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':3})
labels = 'Cafe', 'Lanche1', 'Almoco', 'Lanche2', 'Janta', 'Ceia'
sizes = [20, 5, 30, 15, 20, 10]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral', 'blue', 'pink']
explode = (0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1) #serapação das rfeições
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal') #transforma em círculo

plt.show()
```

Comment: You want to make the figure/pie chart smaller, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly @BobHaffner

Answer (score 9):

To change the size of your pie chart/figure, you could insert the following two lines right above plt.show().

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(2,2) # or (4,4) or (5,5) or whatever
```

Answer (score 8):

You can adjust the overall spacing by starting with these lines:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,.5,1))
ax.set_title('Distribuicao recomendada de calorias por refeicao', 
             bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':3})
```

and continue from the title-line in the original code.

This is making the axis leave room at the top of the figure, by specifying the axis size in figure coordinates. From the docs for `add_axes`:

> Add an axes at position rect [left, bottom, width, height] where all
>   quantities are in fractions of figure width and height.

The figure contains the axes, the axes contain the plots. (The x-axis and y-axis are parts of the axes.)

[image]